# openapi-generator doesn't use description from tags so it doesn't appear in generated files and swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring, openapi-generator

I tried to use such file:

```yml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: test API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://example.com
    description: test server
tags:
  - name: operation-controller
    description: test description
paths:
  /operation/{operationId}:
    post:
      description: test description
      summary: test summary
      tags:
        - operation-controller
      operationId: testOperation
      parameters:
        - name: operationId
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```

I tried using useTags = true but nevertheless codegen makes such file

```java
//start of the file..
@Api(value = "operation", description = "the operation API") // or @Api(value = "OperationController", description = "the OperationController API")
//
```

if I try to use same yml file in https://editor.swagger.io/ it porperly shows controller descriptions from tags.

Can anyone tell me what how to make openapi-generator to set descriptions for APIs?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I've raised a bug here (as I'm also unable to solve this!): https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14395

Comment: In order the tags are supported you have to set in the `<configOption>` `<useTags>true</useTags>`. Look here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md